# How can I delete rest of the line after a second the same specific character on string?

Tags: script, notepad++, macros

```
dagaga2.com:8ddagd1:dbcc:eLXLBdRdd?a'badagahaha
dadadagh.com:299515:dgan6hhna:992969199269196
dad2agh.com:299515:dganhna:992969199269196
dadada5uwuwgh.com:299ju515:dgaenhna:9929691998d269196
dada12d6agh.com:29951ha165:dgaja2nhn126a:992969117123d72199269196
```

How i remove all thing after second colon(:)
 for all lines?
like that?

```
dagaga2.com:8ddagd1:
text:text:text:empty
text:text:text:empty
```

Comment: your question isn't clear now. Why do you have "after second :" in your question and 3 `:`s in your example result?

Answer (score 1):

In the find and replace gui, check the box for `Regular expression`, and enter a query like:

Find What: `(^\S*)(\:)(\S*)(\:)(.*)$`

Replace With: `\1\2`

This will replace `dagaga2.com:8ddagd1:dbcc:eLXLBdRdd?a'badagahaha` with `dagaga2.com:8ddagd1:`.

[image]

Note that you must escape the `:` characters with a leading backslash. Otherwise the regex parser will read them incorrectly.

What you are doing here, it specifying capture groups within the string, in [parentheses](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Then add `(.*)` at the end, to grab all the rest of the string, whatever it may be.

The replace statement is a [Backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html), which says "give me only the first two capture-groups". Capture groups are created by parentheses, which is why we had to put the sought string inside them.

Comment: but if have different text for each line

Comment: what is the same for every line? that there are two colons?

Comment: See my edit. Tested in N++ v6.8.8. works for all examples you posted.

Comment: if appear more  than two colon ":" in the same line won't be deleted all thing after

Comment: I'm afraid I dont understand what you are saying. this replace gives me "dagaga2.com:8ddagd1:
dadadagh.com:299515:
dad2agh.com:299515:
dadada5uwuwgh.com:299ju515:
dada12d6agh.com:29951ha165:" Are you sure you enabled `Regular Expressions`?

Comment: @FrankThomas: I think correct rose with would be `\1\2\3\4`

Comment: @MátéJuhász, yeah, I would think so too but then I actually tried it in N++. There is something weird in the way they enumerate capture groups. (.*\:.*\:)(.*) always grabbed 3 colons worth of stuff in \1. weirdest thing.

Comment: @FrankThomas: the expression in your comment is different from the one in your answer!

Comment: yes, it was another example of N++ miscounting the number of capture groups. That was what we were discussing afterall.

Answer (score 1):

A more general solution compared to Frank Thomas's one:

Find what: `(([^:]*\:){2}).*`
Replace to: `\2`

This will remove everything after second `:`

Comment: won't work for me